# DWG to GeoJSON in QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, geojson, export, convert, dwg

I am Using QGIS 3.18 or 3.10. I have imported a DWG file with many layers and many type of features (hatch, point, polyline). I want to converts them to GeojSON format. Is there a way to export all the layers in one time or do I have to do one by one. It takes a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to BulkVectorExport plugin, which exports all vector layers in the actual project to a given format and SRS. See https://github.com/zsiki/bulkvectorexport